# How to Extract Subfigures Separated by Whitespace in an Image?

Tags: python, graphics, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have a lot of images that are all whitespace except some figures within them. I want to extract all these figures and save them to their own individual file. It seems like there should be a package to do so efficiently, but I just can't find anything. Can any of you give me any pointers?

As an example, for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMiel.png) image, I want to extract all the people and save them each to a single file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1. Calculate an object mask (wherever the object is not equal to the background color) 2. Close all holes in the mask with binary_fill_holes. 3. Label the image, and then use regionprops to get either the bounding box or coordinates of each object.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much!